# how to add dynamically populated cost to a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```js
/* need to populate cost dynamically from a selection ex radio button  */
function calculateCost() {
  var scoop_prices = new Array();
  scoop_prices["single"] = 8;
  scoop_prices["double"] = 14;
  var scoopCost = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["iceCreamForm"];
  var selectedScoop = theForm.elements["typeOfScoop"];
  for(var i = 0; i < selectedScoop.length; i++)
  {
    if(selectedScoop[i].checked) {
      scoopCost= scoop_prices[selectedScoop[i].value];
      break;
    }
  }

  return scoopCost;

  /* issue from here */

  var s3 = document.getElementById("scoopy");
  s3.innerHTML = s3.innerHTML + "Approx xost in $" + scoopCost;
  /* i guess dom is not yet loaded to print the above statement , help me to fix this */
}
```

```html
<div class="choose" id="choosen">
  <form action="" id="iceCreamForm" onsubmit="false;">
    <label>choose the scoop you want</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="s1" name="typeOfScoop" value="single" onclick="calculateCost()"  />single
    <input type="radio" id="s2" name="typeOfScoop" value="double" onclick="calculateCost()" />double<br />
  </form>
</div>
<!--want to display the ouput on selection of any radio buttons above -->
<div id="scoopy"> </div><br />
```

and many radio buttons or other multiple selection buttons followed by this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the problem is that you try to put the html after the `return` statement. Well, once you call `return` the code below never will execute, so, move this code above the `return` statement.

> When a return statement is called in a function, the execution of this function is stopped

<sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return#Description</sub>

Note: if you just need to display the html, you don't need to use `return`. You need this only when you expected to result from the function.

```js
/* need to populate cost dynamically from a selection ex radio button  */
function calculateCost() {
  var scoop_prices = new Array();
  scoop_prices["single"] = 8;
  scoop_prices["double"] = 14;
  var scoopCost = 0;
  var theForm = document.forms["iceCreamForm"];
  var selectedScoop = theForm.elements["typeOfScoop"];
  for(var i = 0; i < selectedScoop.length; i++)
  {
    if(selectedScoop[i].checked) {
      scoopCost = scoop_prices[selectedScoop[i].value];
      break;
    }
  }
  
  var s3 = document.getElementById("scoopy");
  s3.innerHTML = "Approx xost in $" + scoopCost;

  // you don't need it
  // return scoopCost;
}
```

```html
<div class="choose" id="choosen">
  <form action="" id="iceCreamForm" onsubmit="false;">
    <label>choose the scoop you want</label><br />
    <input type="radio" id="s1" name="typeOfScoop" value="single" onclick="calculateCost()"  />single
    <input type="radio" id="s2" name="typeOfScoop" value="double" onclick="calculateCost()" />double<br />
  </form>
</div>
<!--want to display the ouput on selection of any radio buttons above -->
<div id="scoopy"> </div><br />
```

Comment: thanx it is working , but the text getting added is going like a chain reaction on multiple clicks of radio button

Comment: everythig is fine now made few changes  thanx closing this

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with minimal lines of code if you pass the `value(price)` on click of the radio button

**HTML**

Pass the price of scoop as the value of the radio button. `onclick`  pass this value to the handler function. Also note `input` does not have closing tag. You dont need `</input>`. Instead an input should be mapped with a label

```
<input type="radio" id="s1" name="typeOfScoop" value="8" onclick="calculateCost(this.value)" >single
<input type="radio" id="s2" name="typeOfScoop" value="14" onclick="calculateCost(this.value)">double
```

**JS**

`onclick` pass the value to the handler function & update the DOM

```
function calculateCost(price) {
      var s3=document.getElementById("scoopy");
      s3.innerHTML= "Approx xost in $" + price;
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/k5v6gfgg/)